# Stripe İntegration with compose

Tags: kotlin, stripe-payments, android-jetpack-compose

```
class PaymentRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val stripeApi: StripeApi
) {
    suspend fun createCustomer()= withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = stripeApi.createCustomer()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d("PaymentRepository", "createCustomer: ${response.body()}")
            return@withContext response.body()?.let {
                CustomerApiModel(
                    customer = it.customer
                )
            } ?: throw Exception("Body is null")
        } else {
            throw Exception("Error: ${response.code()}")
        }

    }

    suspend fun createEphemeralKey(customerId: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = stripeApi.createEphemeralKey(customerId)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            return@withContext response.body()?.let {
                EphemeralKeyApiModel(
                    ephemeralKey = it.ephemeralKey
                )
            } ?: throw Exception("Body is null")
        } else {
            throw Exception("Error: ${response.code()} ${response.errorBody()?.string()} ")
        }
    }

    suspend fun createPaymentIntent(
        customerId: String,
        amount: Int,
        currency: String,
        autoPaymentMethodsEnable: Boolean
    ) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = stripeApi.createPaymentIntent(
            customerId, amount, currency, autoPaymentMethodsEnable
        )
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            return@withContext response.body()?.let {
                PaymentIntentApiModel(
                    clientSecret = it.clientSecret
                )
            } ?: throw Exception("Body is null")
        } else {
            throw Exception("Error: ${response.code()} ${response.errorBody()?.string()}")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement stripe gateway, but I got an exception saying:

```
createCustomer: CustomerApiModel(customer=) // i tried customerId too
2023-12-13 01:14:15.978 11077-11077 AndroidRuntime          com.example.cheicksa                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
`Process: com.example.cheicksa, PID: 11077                                                                                                     java.lang.Exception: Error: 400 {                                                                                                       "error": {                                                                                                         "code": "parameter_invalid_empty",                                                                                                         "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-empty",                                                                                                         "message": "You passed an empty string for 'customer'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'customer' cannot be unset. You should remove 'customer' from your request or supply a non-empty value.",                                                                                                         "param": "customer",                                                                                                         "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_6TrFDgL1kaZC3t?t=1702419255",                                                                                                         "type": "invalid_request_error"
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. It seems you are passing an empty string inside customer. Have you checked that there is a value inside the customer parameter?